# Can't detect monitor brightness keys in Wayland, but they are detected in X

Tags: x11, keyboard, wayland, brightness, sway

I'm trying to slowly shift my way towards Wayland, but I'm having some trouble with my laptop's media keys. On X, all the ones I need are supported no problem, but when I switch over to Sway, I'm not able to effectively bind anything to them. I've tried using `xev` and `xbindkeys` and my volume and media keys are supported, but the monitor brightness keys don't give me any output. I know it's not the keys themselves, because if I push them using the `Fn` modifier, they show up as they should as `F2` and `F3`.

Is there something up with sway that's causing this, and is there a way to fix it?

Edit: should've mentioned I'm using lighdm as my display manager, it looks like that might be part of the problem. I tried a solution similar to [this one](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/issues/63), but lightdm just restarts if I try to run a script containing `exec sleep 1` or `sleep 1`, lightdm just restarts rather than entering the sway session. Looking through the log, the only abnormal thing looks like this:

```
DEBUG: Activating login1 session 5
WARNING: Error activating login1 session: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.NoSuchSession: No session '5' known
```

And then it stops the session.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was LightDM, I switched to SDDM and the problem was fixed. SDDM doesn't require KDE so it works to be lightweight enough for me.